# cannot get place from google map using location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I try to get place(ex: locality, country, postal code) form google map using
latitude and longitude. The following is my code that got null data:

**Edit:**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    if (location != null) {

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude()/1E6,
                    location.getLongitude()/1E6, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                resultAddress = addresses.get(0);

                locality = resultAddress.getLocality();
                sublocality = resultAddress.getSubLocality();
                postalcode = resultAddress.getPostalCode();
                country = resultAddress.getCountryName();
                adminarea = resultAddress.getSubAdminArea();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I tried to assign latitude and longitude manually, but got nothing.

Any one can correct my mistakes ? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is on the parameters of the method. I guess that **location** is a **GeoPoint** In that case, instead of

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(), 1);
```

try this:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude()/1E6,
                    location.getLongitude()/1E6, 1);
```

because the coordinates in a geopoint are represented in microdegrees

**Edit**
I copied your code and tried it. Assuming your "location" object is a GeoPoint, the code that works is as follows:

```
GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    if (location != null) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitudeE6()/1E6,
                    location.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address resultAddress = addresses.get(0);

                String locality = resultAddress.getLocality();
                String sublocality = resultAddress.getSubLocality();
                String postalcode = resultAddress.getPostalCode();
                String country = resultAddress.getCountryName();
                String adminarea = resultAddress.getSubAdminArea();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

however, if you are testing it on the emulator, be sure you have internet connection. Otherwise, the method "getFromLocation" cannot find out the address and won't display anything. If you don't have any error in the logcat and the problem is only that nothing is displayed, that is the problem: **no network**.

Comment: Can you post your code for your location object? and also, are you sure that the object is not null?

Comment: @Finuka I'm sure the location object is not null bec I show its(lat,lng,place) via textview. The textview shows lat and lng, only information of place is null.

Comment: and when the force close occured, what does the logcat say?

Comment: @Yoo: take a look cause I edited my answer, hope this time can help!

Comment: @Finuka I test it on real mobile and connecting to network, the differences between your edited code and my code are I declared List<Address> and Address resultAddress outside method. I'm not sure about your methods; getLatitudeE6() and getLongitudeE6(), are those your own methods or anything ?

Comment: @Yoo: nop, those methods are from the GeoPoint class (http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html). I'm using API 8 with google maps.

Comment: @Funika Sorry, I never knew. I already edit my code, I added some line before if statement. Geocoder I also declared outside of method. However, at this time I still getting null information. Is it possible that it is not available on my country ?

Comment: jum.. I really don't know. I have the feeling to be skipping something. Why don't you try this coordinates: (28.459353718893468, -16.27699613571167)? They are from my country. You should see something like "Santa Cruz de Tenerife". Which is your country? I can try some coordinates from there, but I think that is not the problem.

Comment: @Funika My country is Thailand(13.672009,100.50396). Actually, I tried coordinates of California at geocoder.getFromLocation() but still get nothing, also your coordinates. Could you please give me a test statement bec I believe I did it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The best thing to find out the problem is using the debug mode. Put a break point on the "if" statement and follow step by step to see the values. When "getFromLocation" is executed, see if it goes to the catch statement. In that case, check the message on the variable windows on the debug view in Eclipse. Then, we can know the exception. I think the code is ok, and if you have internet connection and in the manifest you have the permission and the uses of google maps library, then it should work. Let me know the exception, coz I'm really curious about it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in manifest.xml?