# Does android get user's location by network need Google Map installed

Tags: android, google-maps, networking, geolocation

My problem is the same with

[cannot get place from google map using location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914474/cannot-get-place-from-google-map-using-location)

I installed a new android ROM and tested locationlistener with network location provider, nothing would return back.

But if I install Google Map from Market, and position myself in Google Map by network, it can locate me, and after that, I can locate myself in my app also. It looks like to install Google Market is a must for network locating.

Correct me if I am wrong. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Maps has nothing to do with your network location.

If you enable (on your device settings) and set (in your code) that provider in your app then you can use it too. `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` is what I'm talking about. Read more on the link below.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: I did everything I could, but it failed.